# What is Gilligan's full name?

Tags: character, gilligans-island

Almost everyone knows [Gilligan's Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilligan_(Gilligan%27s_Island)). But can anyone tell me his full name?

I do not think "Little Buddy" counts!

Can someone possibly provide a reference with Gilligan's full name?

Comment: if he's really named Little buddy Gilligan, could it be worse than Chandler Muriel Bing? oh, of course yes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When the first season of "Gilligan's Island" was released on DVD in 2004, it included a short documentary called "Before the Three Hour Tour." That piece featured materials from Sherwood Schwarz's first attempt to put the show together that indicated Gilligan's full name was to be: "**Willy Gilligan**." Schwarz purposely dropped that from the finished product. So, in the official "Gilligan's Island" universe, we never know.

Low quality clip from "Before the Three Hour Tour:"

Comment: And, as stated above, his name is *purposely* omitted in the finished product. Just saying "no" is not much of an answer.

Comment: Was his name given in the movie?  I can't 100% recall because I've not seen it in over 20 years, but if feels like it might have been mentioned.

Comment: This might be improved by a title saying something like "Name was officially dropped." It's easy to read this as saying "Willy" is the answer, rather than just the name that was cut before production.

Comment: Gilligan being the fist mate, would make sense that “Gilligan “ is his last name. Navy personal are always called by their last name. Thus **“Willy Gilligan”** makes more sense than **“Gilligan Whitehead”**.

Answer (score 31):

"Gilligan Whitehead" might be his name, according to another's of Sherwood Schwartz's TV shows.

[Gilligan’s Name (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilligan_(Gilligan%27s_Island)#Name)

> At the end of A Very Brady Sequel, a movie based on The Brady Bunch characters *also created by Sherwood Schwartz*, Carol Brady reveals that her first husband was a professor lost on a boat. *Dr. Whitehead,* played by John Hillerman, says, "and *my son Gilligan was first mate on that boat*."

Comment: Uh, God? Is that a writer or something?

Comment: @AzorAhai https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod (Beware TV Tropes!) "A statement regarding some ambiguous or undefined aspect of a work, the Word of God comes from someone considered to be the ultimate authority, such as the creator, director, **or producer**."  Sherwood Schwartz was the Producer of both GI and The Brady Bunch.

Comment: Yeah, I know what "Word of God" is, but that's definitely a confusing way to write it! haha

Comment: I don't think you can count a movie made 30 years after the fact to be the source for anything official.

Comment: @JohnnyBones it was written (or at least approved) by God in the form of Sherwood Schwartz.  That's IMO more authoritative than a scrapped pilot.

Answer (score -3):

Bob Denver is his real name. My source is:

[Gilligan's Island (1964–1992)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057751/faq) **IMBd**

Comment: Bob Denver is the name of the actor who played Gilligan. Gilligan's *actual* full name is listed in the very same FAQ, two questions down (see "What are Skipper's and Professor's real names, **and Gilligan's last name**?")